# YouTube API Search for Exact Phrase

Tags: php, search, youtube-api, feed

I am using YouTube PHP API to retrieve a feed that searches for the exact term "super bowl commercials".

However, I sometimes get irrelevant videos in the feed.

$searchTerms stores the search query.

```
$searchTerms2 = str_replace(" ","+",$searchTerms);
$searchTerms2 = '"' . $searchTerms2 . '"';

$query->setVideoQuery($searchTerms2);
```

Does any one know of a solution to this issue?

Comment: show us the full api link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reference: `To search for an exact phrase, enclose the phrase in quotation marks. For example, to search for videos matching the phrase "spy plane", set the q parameter to %22spy+plane%22.`

So you `urlencode` your quotation marks?

Comment: I don't have a PHP example, but as long as your url looks like `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=%22super+bowl+commercials%22&orderby=published&max-results=5&v=2` it should be fine. Try to debug it and output the final url to see whats going on in your script.